# Qt Signals and slots mechanism blocked by a loop in main

Tags: qt, signals-slots, event-loop, qt-signals

I have a following situatuion.

- 2 `Socket` objects are created in the main in a `for` loop (*the original problem has 1000 objects*). Upon creation the `start()` method is invoked.
- `start()` creates a `QTcpSocket` which tries to connect to some host.
- `Socket` has slots which catch the `connected()` signal from QTcpSocket and print some debug output

What happens is that chronologically first ALL the `Socket` objects are created after which the sockets are started. Here is an example output of debug options:

```
1. Created Socket object 1
2. Invoked Socket object 1 start()
3. Created Socket object 2
4. Invoked Socket object 2 start()
5. Socket object 1 TcpSocket Connected
6. Socket object 2 TcpSocket Connected
```

**Code:**

```
//main.cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        Socket *socket = new Socket();
        qDebug() << "Socket object created";
        socket->Start();
    }
    return a.exec();
}

//socket.cpp
Socket::Socket(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{}

void Socket::Start()
{
    qDebug()<<"Start method invoked";
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);

    connect(socket,SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(on_connect()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    socket->connectToHost("192.168.5.5",12345);
}

void Socket::on_connect()
{
    QTcpSocket* socket = qobject_cast<QTcpSocket *>(QObject::sender());
    qDebug() << socket->socketDescriptor() <<  " Connected.";
}
```

This is not the behavior I expected because the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html) states:

> When a signal is emitted, the slots connected to it are usually
>   executed immediately, just like a normal function call. When this
>   happens, the signals and slots mechanism is totally independent of any
>   GUI event loop.

***Question**:*

How to ensure the slots are executed "immediately" (not only after the loop in the main finishes) when the signal is emitted?

---

*The only available solution (without introducing new threads) i currently see*:

Drop the use of signals and slots in this case, and implement everything in the `start` method. Something like this:

```
Socket::start(){
...
if(!tcpsocket->waitForConnected(200)) qDebug() << "Socket object X TcpSocket Connected"
...
}
```

Comment: Can you put little bit more code?

Comment: It would be much more useful if you gave an example of the code, rather than a description of it. I can interpret your description in several ways, but would know exactly what source code is doing.

Comment: @Merlin069 Updated with code

Comment: slots are executed immediately after signal was emitted (when directConnection is used or to objects from one thread are connected by AutomaticConnection (default value)). Now probably you are not happy because you are expecting that `Socket object 1 TcpSocket Connected` should be at position `3` not `5`. Problem here is that __SIGNAL__ is emitted after connection was properly established and for that event loop is needed to receive some system notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

establishing the connection happens asynchronously (read `connectToHost` will return immediately before it even checks whether the connection has already been established) and will notify your code using the signals that are triggered by events

these events are handled only in the event loop or when you call WaitForConnect (which will spin up it's own even loop only handling those events)

this means that the sequence you get is perfectly normal

Comment: Signals and events aren't stacked on the same queue?

Comment: they are but you seem confused about the synchronousness of the socket

Comment: You say `these events are handled only in the event loop`. Does that mean that the 'for loop' in main is blocking the population of the event/signal queue? And since there are no signals in the queue no slots are triggered?

Comment: the queue can still be populated but the connection events are only handled in the loop where they are then pushed on the queue

Answer (score 5):

Your slot is indeed triggered immediately when `QTcpSocket`'s signal `connected()` is emitted.

However, `connected()` is not emitted the moment you try to connect that socket to somewhere.

The documentation writes:

> This signal is emitted after connectToHost() has been called
>   and a connection has been successfully established.

The establish of a connection requires an event loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that without introducing new threads, only solution is seems your solution.

Or using DirectConnection instead of leaving it empty (Which is AutomaticConnection and which is QueuedConnection in your case) may be a solution. But I don't think that it will work because you need to wait in order to run that slot. I'm not sure, just give it a try.

Comment: I've manually set it to `Qt::DirectConnection`, didn't work. I believe that was the case since everything is in the same thread so `Qt::AutoConnection` is the same as `Qt::DirectConnection`.

Comment: Then you can't do it, next answer explains why you can't.